# How to delete columns from excel file using Python (OpenPyXL) - delete_cols

Tags: python, openpyxl, delete-row

How can I properly delete column in Python?

When I manually delete column "K" from Excel the rest of the file properly move left, without bugs.
But when I execute my code the file was not generated correctly.
How can I delete columns without such a mess in my file?

I want to delete column "K" by code:

```
cols_list= ['K']

def modify(path):
   
    wb = load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb.active
    sheet = wb["Sheet1"] 
    
    for i in cols_list:
    
        which_cols= openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string(i)
        ws.delete_cols(which_cols, 1)

    wb.save("./data_frames_from_xml_modified.xlsx")
```

The problem is that the modified file don't load properly.

Comment: Your code is fundamentally OK, however has a redundant line.  You have the lines **ws = wb.active** then **sheet = wb["Sheet1"]**. The variable 'sheet' is not used in your code so has no effect. The worksheet variable is 'ws' which points to the sheet which was active when the workbook was last saved. This might not be 'Sheet1'. Delete the **wb.active** line and change 'sheet' to 'ws'; **ws = wb["Sheet1"]** This does not explain your reported error however since the deleted col from whichever sheet should not cause a corrupted workbook. You'd need to expand on what the error is exactly.

Comment: It's likely that other items in the worksheet depend on references to cells that you're deleting.